# Transform GridView column so it shows data from a static array

Tags: php, yii2

Using gii, I created a model based on a database table and then CRUD for the model. One of the columns is showing either 1 or 2 as they are stored in the database. To create new, it was easy using a ActiveForm->dropDownList() widget:

`<?= $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList(['1'=>'Role', '2'=>'Permission'], ['prompt'=>'Select Auth Item Type']) ?>`

How to use GridView and show `Role` instead of `1` and `Permission` instead `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gridview you can use value

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        .........
        [
            'attribute' => 'type',
            'label' => 'Type',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {                      
                 if ( $model->type == 1) {
                    return 'Role';
                 } else {
                    return 'Permission';
                 }
            },
        ],
```